# Error: Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser when i am running my test cases and every thing is fine

Tags: reactjs

Why my test cases are not running and my component is rendering fine?
Test suite failed to run

Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser

```
  1 | import React from 'react';
> 2 | import { getInputStyleClassName } from '@app- 
   utility/stylesManager';
    | ^
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. For me, in my style manager package, I had to put the following in my `webpack.config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: '',
    ...
  },
};
```

You can find more info on this here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/707

Comment: this is not working for me. i am serving a ssr via express that is fetching static spa assets after page reload. i've tried adding this in both webpacks to no avail

Answer (score 0):

this error is coming because of a silly mistake.

I forgot to mention the public path field in my style manager package.